# JUnit Testing multiple functions at once

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am trying to make some Junit tests for a tic tac toe board. I know how to test one function at a time, but my problem is that in order to check some function, previous functions must be called.

For example, in order to check a winner, you have to call the function "PlaceMarker" function multiple times. The specific one I'm on is checking to make sure the bool function "CheckSpace" returns false when there is already a marker in the spot its checking. I currently have

```
public class TestGame {

private GameBoard board;

@Before
public void setUp() {board = new GameBoard();}

@After
public void tearDown() {board = null;}

@Test
public void testRewritingOverSpace() {
  assertEquals("Placing (1, 1), then checking space (1, 1)", false,
  board.placeMarker(new BoardPosition(1, 1, 'X')),
  board.checkSpace(new BoardPosition(1, 1, 'O'));
```

This is giving me a error. So in short, how do you make a JUnit test case in which you have to call multiple functions.

Comment: "This is giving me a error." Without knowing what the error is, it's very hard to help you. It's not clear what assertion you're expecting to make here, to be honest. Perhaps you want to call `board.placeMarker(...)` and then `assertEquals(false, board.checkSpace(...))`? Is it the `checkSpace` method that you're testing in terms of returning false?

Comment: Please provide more details regarding the error you are seeing as well as the version of JUnit you are using.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question: you go step by step. Especially when you consider TDD, you work like this:

- you create a first test for the very first "feature" of your production code
- you implement that feature
- you write another test ... and implement

And yes, that could mean that your code looks like:

```
@Test
public void testFirstFeature() {
  ... one line of setup
  ... invoke method on object under test
  ... assert something
} ...

@Test
public void testMoreAdvancedFeature() {
  ... multiple 
  ...   lines
  ...       of setup

  ... invoke method on object under test
  ... assert something
}
```

And you will probably find that your later test cases do actually *test*/*verify* behaviour that is already covered by tests you wrote earlier on. Then you can step back and ask yourself: "is there some merit in *keeping* this earlier tests - or can I safely throw them away?"

You are correct, balancing is required here: having multiple tests that do the same/similar things leads to "duplication". On the other hand - the more tests you have, the easier it will be for you to change small things here and there - and then receive immediate feedback.

Thus: there is no single answer to this. It is all about context and engineering judgement.